# Push variable into a notification view on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm migrating from laravel 5.2 to 5.3 and I would like to send a custom text when the user wants to reset his password.
I see now, laravel use notifications and the default "theme" is hardcoded in the laravel core.
I have already a view for this (from 5.2) and notifications can use a custom view, so I tried this :

In User.php (model)

```
/**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new SendLinkMailPasswordReset($token, $this->full_name));
    }
```

I create my notification "SendLinkMailPasswordReset" for "override" the laravel one and here my toMail() method:

```
/**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->view('auth.emails.password')
                    ->with
                    (
                        [
                            'user'=> $this->full_name,
                            'token'=> $this->token,
                        ]
                    );
    }
```

If I do a `dd($this->full_name)`, it works but when I reset my password I get `Undefined variable: user`

I don't know if `with` is the right method or if I would like to do is possible.
For information, if I do this in my `sendPasswordResetNotification`

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    { 
        $to=$this->email;
        $user= $this;

        Mail::send('auth.emails.password', ['user'=>$user, 'token'=>$token], function($message) use ($to) {
            $message->to($to)->subject('Reset your password'); 
        } );

    }
```

It works. My use of notifications is it good or in my case I should push a mail instead?

Comment: with will only till next request. it uses flash session

Comment: thanks for your reply. when I read docs https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.html#method_with it said "Add a line of text to the notification." that's why I used it. Do you know an other method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
 $user = $this->full_name;
 $token = $this->token;

 return (new MailMessage)
                ->view('auth.emails.password', compact('user','token'));
```

Access the data in view like

```
{{ $user }}
{{ $token }}
```

Answer (score -1):

An other way, we can use `$viewData` property (https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.html) like that:

```
$viewData=  [
                'user'=>$this->full_name, 
                'token'=>$this->token
            ];
```